# Question on a corollary follows from a logarithmic estimate.

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, logarithms

> **Lemma** $:$ If $|z| \leq \frac {1} {2}$ then for any $k \geq 1$ $$\left |\log (1 - z) + \left (\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k} \frac {z^n} {n} \right ) \right | \leq |z|^{k + 1}.$$

As a corollary of the above lemma the following has been left as an exercise $:$

> **Corollary** $:$ If $|z| \leq 1$ then for any $k \geq 1$ $$\left |1 - (1 - z) \exp \left (\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k} \frac {z^n} {n} \right ) \right | \leq |z|^{k+1}.$$

I am trying to use the inequality $|\exp (z)| \leq \exp (|z|),$ for all $z \in \mathbb C.$ Then for all $z \in \mathbb C$ with $|z| \leq \frac {1} {2}$ we have $$\left |(1-z) \exp \left (\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k} \frac {z^n} {n} \right ) \right | \leq \exp \left (|z|^{k+1} \right ).$$ I have no idea as to how do I proceed from here. Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.